# Find the sum of the series $2, -4, 8 , ...$ to $2p$ terms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the sum of the series $2, -4, 8 , ...$ to $2p$ terms.

This is a geometric progression with factor $-2$.

Given the first term is $2$ and the factor is $-2$,

$s=\dfrac{2[1-(-2)^{2p}]}{1-(-2)} \\ s=\dfrac{2}{3}[1-(-2)^{2p}] \\ s=\dfrac{2}{3}-\dfrac{2(-2)^{2p}}{3} \\ s=\dfrac{2-2^{2p+1}}{3}$

The solution is given as $\dfrac{2}{3}(1-2^{2p})$. Am I correct in saying $(-2)^{2p}=2^{2p}$ because there is a $2$ in the exponent so it will always be an even exponent, and hence the sign will always be positive? And is my calculation to my final expression correct? Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to get the sum to $n$ terms, which involves $(-1)^n$, and then replace $n$ with $2p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of questions may be answered in the affirmative. Your calculation is correct, and we note that
$$
(-2)^{2p} = \big( (-2)^2 \big)^p = (2^2)^p = 2^{2p}
$$